# polymorphic binary tree function

Tags: tree, scheme, racket

I am having trouble doing two HW problems. One of them requires to write a polymorphic binary tree function for insert and search which have the contracts.

```
insert : a (treeof a) (a a -> bool) -> (treeof a)
```

and

```
search : a (treeof a) (a a -> bool) -> bool
```

The contract is

```
;; A bst is either empty or (make-bst n l r) where
;;  n is an alpha, r and l are bst.
(define-struct bst (n l r))
```

I don't really understand the `a a -> bool` part of the contract specifically and it is really getting me confused because I don't really know if I should put a test there or if it should be something else. How would I tackle these functions to accommodate for that 3rd variable?

The 2nd question I have has the following contract:

```
;; A bspt is either
;; - (make-rect c) (the rect represents the leaves of the tree)
;; - (make-bspt s l r) (this is a node with two children
;; Where s is either 'x or 'y, l and r are children
;; and c is a color
(define-struct bspt (s l r))
(define-struct rect (c))
```

and typing out the following:

```
(define t1 (make-bspt 'x (make-rect 'red) (make-rect 'blue)))
(show-tree t1)
```

gives you a square that is divided in two with red being the left side and blue being the right side and

```
(define t2 (make-bspt 'x (make-bspt 'x (make-rect 'green) (make-rect 'red)) (make-rect 'blue)))
(show-tree t2)
```

splits the left side again with the green rectangle being first followed by the original red and then the blue side is left unchanged.

and finally,

```
(define t3 (make-bspt 'x (make-bspt 'x (make-bspt 'y (make-rect 'yellow) (make-rect 'orange)) (make-rect 'red)) (make-rect 'blue)))
(show-tree t3)
```

divides the green part in half, where the top part of the green part is orange and the bottom part is yellow and everything else stays the same. I am having trouble trying to think of a function where if you type out the given functions above, it would give you those corresponding drawings. Any helpful tips/codes would be helpful and appreciated!

Comment: 'a a -> bool' is any function that takes two values of the same type and returns a Boolean. example (define (my-less int1 int2)(< int1 int2)). If 'my-int-tree was a tree of ints, we could write (search 5 my-it-tree my-less). The big idea is that functions are values in the Lisp family of languages. I think  a a -> bool is what you are calling a 'test'.

Comment: @ben It's a binary predicate, of which `<` and `>` are two. The intent, BTW, is to pass those directly, not a wrapping function like `my-less`.

Comment: @chris Aware of that. I was responding to "I don't really understand the a a -> bool part" in the question. I feel this is the right balance between help-with and struggling-on for this particular homework question. The *HtDP* methodology is excellent, but the ideas around higher order functions are still non-trivally grasped despite the *HtDP* notation being far more forgiving than explicit or hindley-milner static typing.

Comment: For my first question, would (define (search x y z o)
  (match y
    [empty #f]
    [(struct bst (n l r))
     (cond
       [(o (z x) (z n)) (make-bst x (insert x y z o) r)]
       [(not 
         (or (o (z x) (z n)) (=(z x) (z n)))) (make-bst x l (insert x r z o))]
       [(eq? (z x) (z n)) #t]
       [else #f])]))                                              work? I can't really seem to get a check-expect to work for some odd reason.

Comment: @user3819900 Do you understand what a a -> bool means now?

Comment: I think I do but my function is not really working.

Comment: Does (insert ...) work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### search

You're really asking many questions at once, so I'll take the simple one to get you started, namely the `search` function.

This is how I would write it (using `null` instead of `empty`, they are equivalent):

```
; contract:  e      is of type a   
;            atree  is of type (tree-of a)
;            equalp is of type (a a -> bool)

(define (bst-search e atree equalp)
  (define (sub atree)
    (and (not (null? atree))
         (or (equalp e (bst-n atree))
             (sub (bst-l atree))
             (sub (bst-r atree)))))
  (sub atree))
```

so `e` is an element of any type, `atree` is an tree, and `equalp` is a equal predicate that can be used for the type of `e`.

For symbols, `equalp` would be `eq?`:

```
(define t1 (make-bst 'blue (make-bst 'red null null) (make-bst 'green null null)))
(bst-search 'blue t1 eq?)
=> #t
(bst-search 'red t1 eq?)
=> #t
(bst-search 'yellow t1 eq?)
=> #f
```

and for strings its `string=?`:

```
(define t2 (make-bst "blue" (make-bst "red" null null) (make-bst "green" null null)))
(bst-search "blue" t2 string=?)
=> #t
(bst-search "red" t2 string=?)
=> #t
(bst-search "yellow" t2 string=?)
=> #f
```

### show-tree

I am not really familiar with the Racket drawing libraries, but a simple show-tree would look like this:

```
(require 2htdp/image)

(define (show-tree tree)
  (cond
    ((bspt? tree) 
     ((if (eq? 'x (bspt-s tree)) beside above) (show-tree (bspt-l tree)) 
                                               (show-tree (bspt-r tree))))
    ((rect? tree) 
     (square 20 'solid (rect-c tree)))))
```

then

```
(define t1 (make-bspt 'x (make-rect 'red) (make-rect 'blue)))
(show-tree t1)
```

[image]

```
(define t2 (make-bspt 'x (make-bspt 'x (make-rect 'green) (make-rect 'red)) (make-rect 'blue)))
(show-tree t2)
```

[image]

```
(define t3 (make-bspt 'x (make-bspt 'x (make-bspt 'y (make-rect 'yellow) (make-rect 'orange)) (make-rect 'red)) (make-rect 'blue)))
(show-tree t3)
```

[image]

These are probably not aligned or sized as they should, but you can do better by doing some calculations based on tree heights:

```
(define (tree-space tree)
  (if (bspt? tree)
      (let ((x (bspt-s tree)))
        (define-values (lx ly) (tree-space (bspt-l tree)))
        (define-values (rx ry) (tree-space (bspt-r tree)))
        (if (eq? x 'x)
            (values (* 2 (max lx rx))      (max ly ry))
            (values      (max lx rx)  (* 2 (max ly ry)))))
      (values 20 20)))

(define (show-tree tree)
  (define (sub tree x y)
    (cond
      ((bspt? tree) 
       (define s (bspt-s tree))
       (define d (if (eq? 'x s) beside above))
       (apply (lambda (x y) (d (sub (bspt-l tree) x y) (sub (bspt-r tree) x y)))
              (if (eq? s 'x) (list (/ x 2) y) (list x (/ y 2)))))
      ((rect? tree) 
       (rectangle x y 'solid (rect-c tree)))))
  (define-values (totx toty) (tree-space tree))
  (sub tree totx toty))
```

yielding

[image]

or something along those lines.